# plot overlap between two datasets using rsid value

Tags: r, matching, overlap, vcf-variant-call-format

I want to plot overlap between two datasets.
My first dataset is:
[image]
dput(rsid_en_vcf[1:43,])
c("rs782629217", "rs782403204", "rs199529001", "rs147880041",
"rs141826009", "rs199826048", "rs200558688", "rs782114919", "rs41304577",
"rs200311430", "rs147114528", "rs200635479", "rs41288741", "rs782167952",
"rs6560827", "rs200242637", "rs144539776", "rs41305669", "rs41288743",
"rs41288743", "rs369736529", "rs148025238", "rs41298226", "rs782272071",
"rs9329304", "rs9329305", "rs137895574", "rs142619172", "rs144154384",
"rs782777737", "rs782796368", "rs782443786", "rs782246853", "rs150779790",
"rs782304204", "rs9329306", "rs144740103", "rs4431953", "rs189892388;rs75953774",
"rs61839057", "rs61839058", "rs145405488", "rs782307404")

My second dataset is:

[image]
dput(en_Brain_Cortex7[1:10,])
structure(list(RSID1 = c("rs2085346", "rs12765102", "rs11250286",
"rs1876899", "rs11250293", "rs4880776", "rs7094850", "rs883660",
"rs4880780", "rs4880487")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))
I want to plot a venndiagram with overlap for these two datasets.
This is what I did:

```
venn.diagram(
    x = list(rsid_en_vcf,en_Brain_Cortex7),
    category.names = c("elasticnet_model","rsid_vcf"),
    filename = 'venn_diagramm.png',
    output=TRUE
)
```

But it gives an error:
Error:
! Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 157608 but subscript `!duplicated(x, fromLast = fromLast, ...)` has size 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help page says the input to the x argument should be a list of vectors. Your `x` was a vector and a data.frame.

This succeeds:

```
library(VennDiagram)
venn.diagram(
+     x = list(rsid_en_vcf,en_Brain_Cortex7$RSID1),
+     category.names = c("elasticnet_model","rsid_vcf"),
+     filename = 'venn_diagramm.png',
+     output=TRUE
+ )
[1] 1
```

The image file was of type png but was 36 MB and  SO refuses to upload it.

> Your image is too large to upload (over 2 MiB).

Changing the resolution to 72 and ht and width to 700 I get:

[image]

Comment: I am able to run the code but the output file .png is not getting generated.

Comment: You probably are not looking in the right place. You can see where R thinks it should be by typing `getwd()`